# Unify two different "resize" functions

Tags: jquery, resize, window-resize

I have two different functions that trigger when window is resized. I would like to reduce my line of code unifying them. Both functions work well separately.

The first function is a way to create a "full-screen", responsive Hero banner.

```
$(window).on("resize",fullScreenHero);

function fullScreenHero(){
    var ancho=$(window).width();
    var altoNav=$("nav").height();
    var alto=$(window).height()-altoNav;
    $("#hero").width(ancho);
    $("#hero").height(alto);
}
```

The second function intends to change the layout of the grid view, removing and adding classes.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
        $('#services .service-col').removeClass('col-4').addClass('col-6');
    } else {
        $('#services .service-col').removeClass('col-6').addClass('col-4');
    }
});

/* ---------- GRID-VIEW --------- */

.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}
```

I tried the following and other variants but didn't work.

```
$(window).on("resize",fullScreenHero,transformColumn);

function fullScreenHero(){
    var ancho=$(window).width();
    var altoNav=$("nav").height();
    var alto=$(window).height()-altoNav;
    $("#hero").width(ancho);
    $("#hero").height(alto);
}

function transformColumn(){
    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
        $('#services .service-col').removeClass('col-4').addClass('col-6');
    } else {
        $('#services .service-col').removeClass('col-6').addClass('col-4');
    }   
};
```

The problem that occurs is that the Hero banner doesn't resize at all. "transformColumn" function works.

Comment: why don't you call `fullScreenHero()` from within your second function?

Comment: very true. But I want to call `transformColumn()` also when the page loads, so I think it would be best this way, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).on("resize",function(){
   fullScreenHero();
   transformColumn();
});
```